# How to allow gboard inside the swift iOS app?

Tags: swift, custom-keyboard, gboard

I'm facing the issue with custom keyboards in my app. I don't know what code should I share, but basically GBoard is not working in my Swift app, it's just doesn't in the list of keyboards just for my app.

Full access granted for GBoard and everything working fine for other apps. What could be the problem? Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Try to make it a default keyboard, also check if GBoard is up to date.

Comment: Checked it, everything’s up to date. Unfortunately I can’t afford this workaround with default keyboard, still it doesn’t work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research it looks to me that it’s an intentional behavior from Apple if your text fields have content mode “username” or “password”. Tested it in some apps - the same result, no custom keyboard for username or password textfield